# Convert "Same" Multiple <Button> Functions to Generic Function with <Select>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have multiple buttons that all do something very similar. How do I use a `<select>` box with one `<button>` to do the same thing with less javascript?

**These are the buttons I want to turn into a `<select>` box with just one button:**

```
<button onclick="SaveAsHTML()">Save As HTML</button>
<button onclick="SaveAsJS()">Save As JS</button>
<button onclick="SaveAsCSS()">Save As CSS</button>
<button onclick="SaveAsTXT()">Save As TXT</button>
```

**Here is my javascript right now:**

```
function SaveAsHTML()
{
    var filename = document.getElementById("txtFilename").value;
    var filename = filename + ".html";
}

function SaveAsCSS()
{
    var filename = document.getElementById("txtFilename").value;
    var filename = filename + ".css";
}

function SaveAsJS()
{
    var filename = document.getElementById("txtFilename").value;
    var filename = filename + ".JS";
}

function SaveAsTXT()
{
    var filename = document.getElementById("txtFilename").value;
    var filename = filename + ".txt";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for shorten up my answer. I guess my English is not that good when talking about codes. Thank you... @jcuenod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet, I don't think it needs much explanation.

I have created an array of file types and used jquery to populate the `<select>` with `<option>`s. Then I just look up which one is chosen when you click the `save` button...

```js
var types = [
  {"extension": "html", "name": "HTML"},
  {"extension": "txt", "name": "Plain Text"},
  {"extension": "js", "name": "Javascript"},
  {"extension": "css", "name": "CSS"},
]
types.forEach(function(type) {
  $opt = $("<option>").attr("value", type.extension).text(type.name)
  $("#saveas").append($opt)
})

function SaveAsType()
{
    console.log($("#saveas").val())
    /**
     * Put your code here and replace:
     document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value + ".html";
     * with
     document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value + "." + $("#saveas").val();
     */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Save as <select id="saveas">
</select><button onclick="SaveAsType()">save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. It works PERFECT. Now I wonder is there a way to do it without using "jquery"? If not then I will simply use jquery, but i would rather want it to be independent from jquery, if possible. Sadly I can not give you a like because I need over 15 in reputation and right now I have only 11. This is because I have just started using this page. I had this account before for a very long time, but I never used it till now.

Comment: @SeekLoad You should be able to accept the answer with a rep of 11. It's easy to do this without jquery - I'm only using jquery to fill the `<select>` with `<option>`s so my use of it is completely unrelated to your question so you can build your `<select>` element however you want. I used jquery because you tagged your question with jquery.

Comment: @SeekLoad also, I have edited your question substantially to show you how to ask better questions in future. Try to reduce your code to what is essential, it makes answering the question much easier. If possible make it the kind of question that will get answers others can benefit from.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will make it shorter in the future. And yes I can see and accept the answer with rep of 11, I was talking that I can not give like without rep of 15. i wanted to give you a +1 like.